# Turning a float into an integer without rounding the decimal points

Tags: python, floating-point, type-conversion

I have a function that makes pseudorandom floats, and I want to turn those into integers,
But I don't mean to round them.
For Example, If the input is:

**1.5323665**

Then I want the output to be:

**15323665**

and not **2** or **1**, which is what you get with round() and int().

Comment: `int(str(your_number).replace(".", ""))`

Comment: What should .25 produce? 25 or 250 or 2500? Why? If the value is 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125 but is printed as “0.3333333333333333”, should the result be 333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125 or 3333333333333333? What distribution of integers are you seeking to produce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to string and remove a dot:

```
int(str(x).replace('.', ''))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first convert the float to a string and then remove the decimal point and convert it back to an `int`:

```
x = 1.5323665
n = int(str(x).replace(".", ""))
```

However, this will not work for large numbers where the string representation defaults to scientific notation. In such cases, you can use string formatting:

```
n = int(f"{x:f}".replace(".", ""))
```

This will only work up to 6 decimal places, for larger numbers you have to decide the precision yourself using the `{number: .p}` syntax where `p` is the precision:

```
n = int(f"{1.234567891:.10f}".replace(".", ""))
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than creating your own pseudorandom engine, which almost-certainly won't have a good [density distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function), especially if you coerce floats to ints in this way, strongly consider using a builtin library for the range you're after!

More specifically, if you don't have a good distribution, you'll likely have extreme or unexplained skew in your data (*especially* values tending towards some common value)

You'll probably be able to observer this if you graph your data, which can be a great way to understand it!

Take a look at the builtin `random` library, which offers an integer range function for your convenience

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint

```py
import random
result = random.randint(lowest_int, highest_int)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = 1.5323665
y= int (x)
z= str(x-y)[2:]
o = int(len(z))
print(int(x*10**o))
```

it will return 15323665